# Should there be a vapor barrier for between two drywall layers?

Tags: vapor-barrier

The noise from outside was really bothering me in one of the rooms in my house, so I decided to address it by installing additional layers of drywall on top of my existing finished walls, with resilient channels placed between them as illustrated in the diagram below. While I understand that this setup may not be highly effective in blocking noise, the primary benefit is that it nearly doubled the thickness of my window sills (not depicted in the picture), thereby enhancing the effectiveness of my window inserts through an increased air gap.

My main question pertains to whether a vapor barrier is necessary in this setup. I am thinking that the old finished wall will now be cold, resulting in condensation in that wall. The space between the old and new drywall layers is currently empty. Is there a specific kind of insulation I should be putting there? Alternatively, is there a specific treatment method for the new drywall that obviates the need for a vapor barrier in this scenario?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I would think a couple layers of paint plus sealing the top and bottom and any holes should limit vapour almost as well as a vapour barrier.  I would seal the original drywall as well to limit moisture from coming into the dead space.